# Why 0 is coming at the end of the linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have been learning Linked List lately & was trying to add a node at the beginning of a linked list.But  in the output an extra '0' comes at the end.Can somebody explain the reason & suggest some changes I should make?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
struct node{
  int num;
  struct node *link;
};
void push(struct node **head,int val){
  struct node *ptr=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  ptr->num=val;
  ptr->link=*head;
  *head=ptr;
}
void trav(struct node *ptr){
  while(ptr!=NULL){
    cout<<ptr->num<<endl;
    ptr=ptr->link;
  }
}
void main(){
  clrscr();
  int val;
  struct node *head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
     cout<<"enter a value:";
     cin>>val;
     push(&head,val);
  }
  trav(head);
  getch();    
}
```

output looks like this
3
4
12
6
7
0

Comment: Because you allocate a `head` node that's not needed. And more importantly, it is not initialized which means it's `link` pointer have an indeterminate value and you are actually having [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) and are just lucky you don't print way more "nodes".

Comment: @abhishek gupta Is it a C or C++ program?

Comment: To add to Joachim's comment, just count how many times you do a `malloc` of a `head` structure... 5 in the for and one *before* it, so you have six nodes in your list.

Comment: Yes I got it.THANKS for help

Answer (score 0):

In the main function you have

```
  struct node *head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
```

Now what is `head->num`? It is zero (given by the compiler).

So in essence, you are creating an empty node before you go to the loop. Hence, it is always printed at the end.

Comment: it's not zero after "mallocing", it's undef value.

Comment: it's the other thing that you want it to be zero, so you use memset or ZeroMemory

Comment: Or `calloc`, which is like `malloc` followed by `ZeroMemory`.